# Moving several files to trash in Mac terminal without using rm, any plugins?

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line, macos, trash

Looking for a way to:

Move several files to the Mac trash in terminal without using the rm, crazy regex,finder, or something destructive.

Today I realized I was just asking the wrong question.

Once I figured out it was just moving several files to "another directory" (in my case ~/.trash), this result came up in [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67503/move-all-files-with-a-certain-extension-from-multiple-subdirectories-into-one-di?newreg=70d3a746fbae4abc8a9685f2fd051979).

I've modified a find command harvested there for my needs...

Continuing with the .zip example: Once you're in the parent directory, just run... `find . -name '*.zip' -exec mv {} ~/.trash \;`

My question is... Is there a way to do it with the [trash plugin](https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash) which has it's advantages like keeping "put back" alive?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a "trash" command available via brew, have you checked that out?

Comment: Your comment had me digging around a bit more. I'm going to uninstall "trash" plugin and try "trash CLI" it looks like it's better at taking expressions. https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash-cli

Comment: Good news, bad news. I figured out the command to use with the plugin. It's not shorter because you need the path to the executable. It doesn't perserve "put back" (maybe it's how Catalina works.) I did however switch to the homebrew version for better maintenance. https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/trash Here's how the command would go... ` find . -depth -name '*.zip' -exec /usr/local/bin/trash {} \;`

Comment: The new line came from clues in this somewhat related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590375/recursively-unzip-files-and-then-delete-original-file-leaving-unzipped-files-in

Comment: If it doesn't preserve the **Put Back** function of **Move to Trash** from **Finder**, why even use a third-party utility?

Comment: Fair question, it still makes trashing one off files pretty easy from the terminal without destroying the file. I also expect the 'put back' thing will be fixed eventually. Example: `trash foo.txt` or `trash "*.txt"` These would target the directory you're currently in.

Comment: It seems the developers are aware of issues with 'put back', and it's a known bug: https://github.com/sindresorhus/macos-trash/issues/4 and Apple has blown this problem off for some time.